# Google Sign In - googleUser is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin, google-identity

I have been following the Google sign in tutorials in order to create a login system and I am at the point where I have a sign in button that loads the widget to select sign in. Once clicked, this should load this function:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
```

However, once I select the account and sign in, nothing happens. In the developer console, when I type in "googleUser" it just says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: googleUser is not defined

Here is all of my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="451815931731-u24ino5uecga1arf65814fd72201fcmu.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  
  <title>S6C Admin Panel</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="imports.html">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signin.css">
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <core-toolbar>
    <span flex>S6C Admin Panel</span>
    <core-icon-button onclick="takeBack()" icon="arrow-back">Back to S6C Website</core-icon-button>
  </core-toolbar>
  <img id="logo" src="../s6clogo.jpg"></img>
  <center>  
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  </center>
  <script>
    function takeBack(){
      window.location.href = "http://s6c.org";
    }
    
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note running the snippet will not work

Comment: What's the result of gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse() ? (after signing in).

Comment: When I input that into the Dev console, it just prints "Object {}" on a new line

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work. Since you're using webcomponents, is using https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin an option for you?

Comment: No unfortunately it hasnt in my tests, only have 1 week left for the assignment so im scrapping it as its not needed for the pass! Cheers though

Comment: add onFailure callback to sign in button `function onFailure(error){console.log(error)}` `<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-onfailure="onFailure"></div>` and look at the returned error

Answer (score 7):

I was with the same problem and using [Jarosław](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256609/jaros%C5%82aw-gomu%C5%82ka)'s tip I managed to solve this.

The solution:

```
function onSignIn() {
  const googleUser = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
  const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to get profile since OAUTH v2

Answer (score 0):

Try add additional meta:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="451815931731-u24ino5uecga1arf65814fd72201fcmu.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
<meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="https://schema.org/AddAction" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
```

and make sure in your google Api Manager, in Credential, in OAuth 2.0 client IDs, check your Authorized JavaScript origins, make sure you enter your origin site where your page running come from. if you develop in localhost add http://127.0.0.1 as your origins script.